# Jquery Ajax function clear text after submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I using Jquery Ajax function login. Now what I want to do is clear the input text after click the button submit.

Here it's my JS code

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#login").click(function()
        {
            var action = $("#login_form").attr('action');
            var form_data =
            {
                username: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val(),
                ajax_login: 1
            };

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: action,
                data: form_data,
                success: function(response)
                {
                    if(response == 'success')
                        window.location.replace("home");
                    else
                        $("#message").html("<div class='error_log'><p class='error'>Invalid username and/or password.</p></div>");  
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Anyone have an suggestions ?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this by `$("#username").val('');` and `$("#password").val('');`

Answer (score 4):

You can do that in the `complete :` callback of the ajaxrequest .. Just clear the fields of your form by passing an empty string to the `.val()` . This function is run as soon as the ajax request is completed..

```
complete: function(){
     $("#username").val('');
     $("#password").val('');              
 }
```